# Why form._errors is working in generic.UpdateView but not in generic.CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, mixins

When I use this in my mixins

```
form._errors[forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS]=ErrorList(["age must be positive"])
```

in my UpdateView it works and the message is popped out in red. But in my CreateView nothing is popping out

How can I achieve this?
Here's my **mixin.py**:

```
class AgePositiveMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.instance.age)
        if form.instance.age>0:
            return super(AgePositiveMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            form._errors[forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS]=ErrorList(["Age must be positive"])
          # raise forms.ValidationError('Age must be positive')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CreateView` doesn't have an `instance` because an object doesn't exist yet when the form is constructed. Instead of `form.instance`, you can do this:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
# perform validation here
instance.save()
return super(AgePositiveMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Is the age supposed to be positive everywhere (in the Django admin, user-facing forms)? If so a [`PositiveSmallIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) will do that validation for you.

In general, I like to keep validations as close to the database as possible. If that `PositiveSmallIntegerField` doesn't fit your use-case, I'd recommend using a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/). With validators, Django will perform the validation for you in the admin, model forms, and anywhere else. It's great for consistency.

Edit: one more way to perform validation is to do it in a form class:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def clean_age(self):
        age = self.cleaned_data['age']
        if not age > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Age must be positive")
        return age
```

Check out Django's [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) docs for more information on this.

Comment: thank you for the answer.
I know about the PositiverField in the model but I just want to show the error message, this code is not real it&#39;s just an example.
I will read the validator doc
UPDATE
Actually the age field I can read it and print it son I can check if it's positive and stop the form from being validated by calling form_invalid. My problem is just showing the message. There has to be a way to do so. For exemple if a unique constraint fails a builtin message pops. I want to do the same thing with custom condition

Comment: @CHEMSEDDINEHAROUIT If using a validator doesn't work for you, you can perform validation for that field that in the form class itself. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried with the clean_age() validation but it's not working (even with a negative age the object is created)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you (my mistake was that clean_age() was inside Meta.

Comment: @CHEMSEDDINEHAROUIT Glad I could help!